# Sublime Text: Find word on same line as each cursor

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have multiple cursors on line with some content that is of variable length and some that's the same content. Due to the variable length content, the lines don't align with each other.

I start with a cursor on each line. I know that only by moving one word at a time to the right, I might not end up at the same spot on each line due to variable content.

How can I do an incremental find for each cursor on the same line and end up with multiple cursors that match my find expression?

Comment: Are you asking about multiple selection? Press Alt+F3 on Windows and Linux, or Ctrl+Command+G on OS X. This will select all instances of the content. If you really want to be incremental then press Ctrl+D on Windows and Linux, or Command+D on OS X.  https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/multiple_selection_with_the_keyboard.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

1. Start with your multiple cursors (done manually, Alt+Enter after a search, etc.)
2. Select the whole line for each cursor (using Home then Shift+End; etc.)
3. Open up the search and enable the "In Selection" option (to the right of the "Wrap" option)
4. Perform your search on those lines, then Alt+Enter to select that match

This would work unless you have multiple matches on the same line. In this case you'll have multiple cursors on the same line